# Why doesn't onLocationChanged method get called in service?

Tags: android, service, gps, location

I am getting my current location in the form of latitudes and longitudes. My problem is that once I get the coordinates it doesn't get updated when I move to another location.I think onLocationChanged method is not getting called. I read here   http://www.lengrand.fr/2013/10/onlocationchanged-is-never-called-on-android/ that it doesn't get called by itself. I have gone through most of the tutorials and can't find a solution.So how can I call  onLocationChanged method in my service. Please suggest me step by step.

My codes are as follow:

```
  public   class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
 public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}
}



             @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    getLocation();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you requestLocationUpdates(...) from the LocationManager (which in your case it seems you do)
- If your inside a building and your device doesn't get GPS fix onLocationChanged(...) is not called, I had the same issue (when debugging in my home) but going outside I saw that the function is called once GPS fix is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    @Override
       public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
       {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Position !!!"+ location.getLatitude + location.getLongitude,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```

Comment: This might cause undesirable behavior. Depending on the update frequency, `onLocationChanged()` may fire well before the current Toast has finished, and eventually lead to a backlog of queued Toasts that will continue to appear for a long while even after the request has been stopped.

Answer (score 0):

It is weird that you are even getting a single location update. From you code it looks like you call getLocation() when you recieve a location change, but you then only setup your location requests inside of the getLocation() function (i.e. you should never enter the getLocation() function). This is how I implemented a location listener for gps data:
Note: I used this in a service, but I did not have my service implement LocationListener.

```
private void setupLocationUpdates() {

    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        // Called when the location has changed.
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mLocation = location;
            }
        }
        // Called when the provider is disabled by the user.
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Status Changed: " + String.valueOf(status) + " Provider:" + provider);
        }
        // Called when the provider is enabled by the user.
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            if(provider.equalsIgnoreCase("gps")) setNotification(Constants.GPS_ENABLED);
            Log.d(TAG, "Provider: " + provider + " ENABLED");
        }
        // Called when the provider status changes.
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            if(provider.equalsIgnoreCase("gps")) setNotification(Constants.GPS_DISABLED);
            Log.d(TAG, "Provider: " + provider + " DISABLED");
        }
      };
    mlocationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    // Register for location updates 
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mlocationProvider, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
    // Add a GPS Listener to notify when searching for signal and when fix is acquired
    mGpsListener = new GpsListener();
    mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(mGpsListener);
}
```